# How to push to c# array when array is in parent class?

Tags: c#, arrays, push

I am attempting to push the string values I have generated into an array which is in the parent class. I am attempting to make a simple deck of cards so I can then build methods around drawing cards and shuffling ect.

This is the first c# I have written, I have more experience with JS and JS would allow me to simply push the value into a parents collection.

I have tried to push the value in the foreach value code block but this does not work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{

    public enum Suit
    {
        Clubs,
        Diamonds, 
        Hearts, 
        Spades
    }

    public enum value
    {
        Ace, 
        Two, 
        Three, 
        Four,
        Five, 
        Six, 
        Seven, 
        Eight, 
        Nine, 
        Ten, 
        Jack, 
        Queen, 
        King, 
    }
    class Deck
    {
        //Array to store deck strings. 
        private string[] DeckList = new String[52];


        class Card
        {
            //Var to hold description text


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                foreach (string rank in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Suit)))
                {

                    foreach (string value in Enum.GetNames(typeof(value)))
                    {
                            string DescriptiveText;
                            DescriptiveText = value + " of " + rank;
                            //I want to push the descriptivetext value into the DeckList string Array. 
                            Console.WriteLine(DescriptiveText);
                    }

                }
                Console.ReadKey();

                // Go to http://aka.ms/dotnet-get-started-console to continue learning how to build a console app! 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I expect an array to be populated, I would like to console log the contents of the array rather than console the values as they are generated. Any input is greatly appreciated, this is simply for the learning experience so I can understand the basics of c#.

Comment: To answer you question, to add to DeckList from outside its class it must be public. That said...You probably want a `List` not an `array`, in C# arrays are functionally equivalent to arrays in C and have very few operations (e.g. no push/add/append/etc). To add to an array you have to use index `deck[i] = card()`. A `List` (or with generics `List<T>`) is almost always better and has an `Add()` method. You also probably don't want your `main()` method to be inside `Card`, you should create a class to be the entry point of your program and have main there as `Card` is very specific.

Comment: Thanks, I not have a list which I have converted to an array. I can tell I am writing this as if it is JS but I have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would not have the Card class defined in the Deck class. I would define them separately and create an array of Card in Deck:

```
class Deck
{
    private IList<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

    public Deck()
    {
        foreach (string rank in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (string value in Enum.GetNames(typeof(value)))
            {
                cards.Add(new Card(rank, value));
            }
        }
    }

    // Call cards[i].GetFullName() if you want the name.
}

class Card
{
    private Suit _suit;
    private Name _name;

    public Card(Suit suit, Name name)
    {
        _suit = suit;
        _name = name;
    }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return _name + " of " + _suit;
    }
}
```

Also I wouldn't build classes around your Main() function. That's the entry point of the program. Build your classes outside of Main(), then instantiate them from within Main():

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Deck deck = new Deck();

    // Whatever functions you define in the Deck class, call them here.
}
```

Edit: Having seen the comment on the original question, I agree that a List would be easier than an array, so I've made that change.

Comment: This is super helpful, the only question I am left with is where would I loop through the enums to generate the strings. I assume it wont be inside the actual card or deck classes?

Comment: I'd assume that the suits and numbers wouldn't change no matter how many decks you create, so I'd do it in the Deck constructor (I've edited my answer).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, could I ask, why the main void block is stating that this name space cannot contain methods fields or methods as what you are saying is call the methods in main.

Comment: That usually happens when you try to write code directly into the namespace block, instead of inside a class within the namespace block.

Comment: ok, so static void should not be called in the same namespace as the deck and card class?

Comment: main() can be in the same namespace as those classes, but it should be within its own class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188147/discussion-between-oliver-nicholls-and-simon-dean).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this line into your second foreach code in Card Class.

```
cards.Add(new Card(rank, value));
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to just console log them but I will do that ion the main